# How Can I Paste A Google Sheets Range with everything except Values?

Tags: google-sheets

Trying to copy a range and paste only formulas, formatting, and data validation (no values) at the end of my sheet so I can enter new values in the freshly pasted range.  All is working except I can't figure out how to exclude values when pasting.

Here is my code:

```
function addCue() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // copy the first cue range as template
  var copyCueRange = ss.getRange("A10:AA11");
  // Find the end of the sheet and set pasteRange to match copyRange
  var l = ss.getDataRange().getValues().length;
  var pasteCueRange = ss.getRange( "A"+(l+1)+":AA"+(l+2) );
  // This pastes all data, How do I paste without values?
  copyCueRange.copyTo(pasteCueRange);
};
```

I am very new to coding and appreciate the help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Data Validation: the `Range` class has a couple of methods for getting and setting data validation rules, `setDataValidations()` and `getDataValidations()`.

Formulas: just as data validation, `Range` also has get/set methods for formulas, `setFormulas()` and `getFormulas()`.

Formatting: looks like the `Range.copyTo()` method has some options specified [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options). Try using the `formatOnly` additional parameter.

```
    function addCue() {
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        // copy the first cue range as template
        var copyCueRange = ss.getRange("A10:AA11");
        // Find the end of the sheet and set pasteRange to match copyRange
        var l = ss.getDataRange().getValues().length;
        var pasteCueRange = ss.getRange( "A"+(l+1)+":AA"+(l+2) );

        //Getting data validation and formulas
        var dataValidationRules = copyCueRange.getDataValidations();
        var formulas = copyCueRange.getFormulas()

        //Setting formatting, data validations, and formulas
        copyCueRange.copyTo(pasteCueRange, {formatOnly:true});
        pasteCueRange.setDataValidations(dataValidationRules);
        pasteCueRange.setFormulas(formulas);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, BaconSodas.  Unfortunately adding formatOnly as an additional parameter results in only the formatting being pasted.  In addition to the formatting, I would like the formulas and data validation to be copied and pasted as well.  That way users can input new values in some of the newly pasted cells and the sheet can make calcs accordingly.

Comment: I gave it another go, is this functionality what you were looking for?

Comment: Thank you. Yes - except pasteCueRange.setDataValidation(dataValidationRules); should be pasteCueRange.setDataValidations(dataValidationRules);  so that it pasts the range. With that edit it works perfectly!! I now understand that each of these elements must be copied and pasted separately. Thank you so much, again!! (also not sure how to properly format code in these comments - sorry)

Comment: Oh no.  Discovered that relative cell references in formulas are not updating when pasted with this script.  Is there a way to have the formulas update their cell references when pasted using this script?  Sorry I didn't notice that before.

Comment: So, I'm entirely sure what you mean by updating cell references, but if you're looking for formulas that reference other cells relative to where they are pasted, check out the [R1C1 notation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFormulaR1C1(String)).
You might have to update your `copyCueRange` template to follow this notation and then use `var formulas = getFormulasR1C1()` and `setFormulasR1C1(formulas)`

Comment: I've been enjoying learning more about sheets by trying to solve your problem! Thanks for asking it!

Comment: Thank you so much.  I appreciate your help.